# How to iterate Wordpress categories to create filter checkboxes by categories on a sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

In my sidebar.php, I want to create filter checkbox on the sidebar as depicted in the above image.  So my filter checkboxes would like in this hierachical format:

Animals

- Bears
- Gibbons
- Rhinos
- Orangutan

Campaigns

- Free the Bears
- The Orangutan Project
- The Silvery Gibbon Projet

I looked up the codex, and found a couple of useful properties on the array object *get_categories*.

However, I'm struggling to come up with my own data structure algorithm to produce the above results so my knowledge in data structure algorithm is fairly weak and I haven't practiced much, especially in PHP.  I'm just wondering is there anybody in the community who's done similar functionality as I'm trying to do right now and be able to show me how it's to be done?

Look forward to your feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to do this.

Here's my code structure.

```
<h2>Sidebar</h2>

<?php 

//Retrieve top-level categories
$parent_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 0
);

//Retrieve first-level categories
$firstchild_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 0, //needs dynamic code here
    'hide_empty' => 0
);


$parent_categories = get_categories($parent_args);


foreach($parent_categories as $parent_category){


//create main headings for other categories other than Uncategorized.
if($parent_category->name!="Uncategorized"){
    $category_label = "Filter By ";
    echo '<h3 style="font-size: 20px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);text-shadow: 2px 3px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0);">'.$category_label.''.$parent_category->name.'</h3>';

    //fetch the parent category's id
    $firstchild_args['parent'] = $parent_category->term_id;
    $firstchild_categories = get_categories($firstchild_args);

    //fetch all the first level children categories
    foreach($firstchild_categories as $firstchild_category){
        $output = "";
        $output = $output."<label class=\"checkbox\">";
        $output = $output."    <input type=\"checkbox\"><span style='font-size: 17px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);text-shadow: 2px 3px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0);'>".$firstchild_category->name;
        $output = $output."</label>";

        echo $output;
    }

}

}

?>
```

It will have to do for now till I refactor this into make better code structure.

Next to create post events for each filter checkbox selected... :)